# Are redux store values up-to-date in the React.callback method that just updated them?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, usecallback

If I call a useCallback method to update a redux store value that is in its dependency array, will I get the updated value immediately or on the next call of the method?

For example, if the `value` in this example is `5` when I call the method, will I log 5 or 10?

```
const doSomething = React.useCallback(async () => {
    await dispatch(changeValue(10));
    console.log(value);     
}, [value]);
```

I think that there is a chance it could be if the update is fast enough, but I would like to know what is the expected behavior.

Comment: `useCallback` returns a memoized version of a function in which the local scope `value = 5`. Even if the update was fast (although this is not important, because the value will change only in the next render cycle) you will always get 5 in cosnole.

Comment: Thank you :). If you make it an answer, I can accept it.